# Scheme Procedure Repeatedly Apply

Tags: scheme, racket, procedure

I want to create a scheme procedure such as;

```
(repeatedly-apply p n) of type (A->A),number->(A->A)
```

It returns a procedure that takes a single argument and applies `p to it n times`

for example;

```
((repeatedly-apply inc 10) 2) => 12
```

Extra Informations:
There is a function that defined and we can use it if we want

```
(define compose (lambda (f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x)))))
```

And we can use the base case as `(lambda (x) x)`

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your attempt at solving the question, otherwise it looks like you're asking to get your homework done for free ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez check following lines

Comment: I don't mind doing their homework if I am awarded their degree.

Comment: @TahaYasinErel The question doesn't contain any code for the `repeatedly-apply` function, please add it.

Answer (score 1):

To create a function which repeatedly applies *f* *n* times:

- if *n* < 1 this is an error;
- if *n* = 1 the answer is *f*;
- otherwise compose *f* with a function which repeatedly applies *f* *n* - 1 times.

You owe the usenet oracle four magic lantern slides and the colour blue.